# Storing Images in android from web services

Tags: android

I am able to handle images and text from web URL's in android using AsyncTask, but have a separate question in mind.

Which approach is best suited for **storing pictures** for one time loading?

IE: Either in an SD Card or in SQLite DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store images for just one time loading, you don't need to store it in Sdcard. You better use a library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). It does all the hard work of caching and managing memory for you. It has very simple API.

```
    Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(imageView);
```